# How to identify a paragraph?

Tags: 8, paragraphs

Is there a way to identify a paragraph in Drupal 8. Like is there a function to get the type as paragraph in code level?

I need to get it from a form alter function. My requirement is to get all the paragraphs in a form. Or identify the paragraph fields.

Comment: try `$paragraphs->bundle();` or `$paragraphs->getType();`

Comment: @NoSssweat Thanks ! but i need to get it from a form alter function. My requirement is to get all the paragraphs in a form. Or identify the paragraph fields.

Comment: Can you not do this within `TEMPLATE_preprocess_paragraph` ?

Comment: Can you add more details about the form? Is it an entity add/edit form or a custom one?

Answer (score 1):

You probably should look at the paragraphs module code, it does a lot of this.

That said, the basic process would probably be:

- Identify the form fields that are entity_reference_revision fields.
- Check that the field is limited to paragraph types (can just check
  1st one).
- If it is an update form, get the referenced entities from the field.
- You will then need some recursive code to walk the paragraph tree to
  get sub paragraphs.

This will require using a lot of the field definition classes to get the information needed.